# Date in SQL reporting service, default to US

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 server we are setting up with SQL Report Server running on SQL 2012. Everything is working fine, but when you put in a date parameter, then click apply the date format reverts to US based (MM/DD/YYYY) after displaying the report. Before clicking it displays in UK format (DD/MM/YYYY) and also running the report in the SQL Report Builder itself, it stays as UK.

I've checked both SharePoint and SQL server and they are all UK region at the OS level. I have changed the SQL server language to UK. When running SELECT @@Language, @@Langid it shows British 23. All login users are set to British.

I have followed various online suggestions and still whenever I click apply in the report on SharePoint the date changes. I have no idea where or why the date format is changing?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to check Central Administration settings if they are well set up. [Here](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/central-administration-regional-settings-in-sharepoint-2010/) is how to do this.

You can also check out on the site level. [Here](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2011/06/08/sharepoint-language-settings-and-regional-settings.aspx) is how.

Hope if helps,

Andrew

Comment: I've already checked all of that. Everything is set to UK. SharePoint, OS, SQL everything. I don't understand where its getting the US date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define property UICulture="en-GB" at the end of "<%@ Page  ..." part of aspx page RSViewerPage.aspx. Page can be found in this location: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ReportServer
Additional info [here](http://www.tachytelic.net/2013/01/changing-the-format-of-date-parameters-on-a-sql-server-2012-reporting-services-report-that-is-sharepoint-integrated/)